# .htaccess mod_rewrite with dynamic folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have been trying this for a little while nut just cannot get to work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^])/([^])\.php$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I have a site:
www.mysite.com/dummyfolder/file.php

I want it to actually load:

www.mysite.com/file.php

FYI - dummyfolder is dynamic and thus changes.

The more complex part, is I would like to be able to ignore this on certain folders, for example be able to access: www.mysite.com/acutalfolder/file.php. Where acutalfolder exists and does not change its name.

Thanks so much - it has really been bogging me down and just cannot figure it out.

**Ansari, thank you for answering and solving, however I need to correct my actual folder statement:**

My actual folder is located here:

```
www.mysite.com/acutalfolder/file.php
```

but I want to appear in the URL like this:

```
www.mysite.com/dummyfolder/acutalfolder/file.php
```

if i use this (to try and ignore if I am using actualfolder):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(!^actualfolder$)/([^/]+)\.php$ /$2.php [L,QSA]
```

It works fine going to the actualfolder address, but then the original rewrite pages no longer work. Any ideas where I am hitting this wrong?

**UPDATE** After help from Ansari. This now works beautifully with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(actualfolder/.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?!actualfolder)([^/]+)/(.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ /$2.php [L,QSA]
```

As for when actualfolder exists, you don't need to do anything for that, unless you do some rewriting in another .htaccess file within actualfolder.

**EDIT** after OP re-did the question:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(actualfolder/.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If I ignore the original rewrite rule you posted, the actualfolder works now, but the dummyfolder does not. It is still one or the other. I have even appended [L] after the %2 and no joy.

Comment: Just updated the rule - you only need the 3 lines after the EDIT statement. Ignore the first rule I gave you.

Comment: Just tried it again, the actualfolder does not want to play ball at the mo. I appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: Still no unfortunately. I have updated my .htaccess file and the dummyfolder is still overruling the actualfolder path.

Comment: Hopefully this can explain the overruling: I know what may be causing the issue, it is because the same file physical file exists in both areas! For example, physical files are: /register.php and /actualfolder/register.php

Comment: In that case, it's best to separate them into two rules. Check my answer in a minute for the new set of rules.

Comment: still seems to be displaying the /register.php and not /actualfolder/register.php file after visiting mysite.com/dummyfolder/actualfolder/register.php. Hmm. It all looks logical. I am going to revisit in the morning as I have spent all night on this and cant see the wood for the trees. Thankyou so much Ansari.

Comment: Hmmm. You're welcome. Did you try with the current set of rules? I switched the order after editing once.

Comment: Yes, I did. There will be something silly I am doing wrong, as this should be black and white - thanks again! :)

Comment: I managed to sort it out. I have edited my original post above.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. Not sure why you have to explicitly say "not actualfolder" in the rule, but if it works for you, great :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** After help from Ansari. This now works beautifully with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(actualfolder/.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?!actualfolder)([^/]+)/(.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %2 [L,QSA]
```

Many thanks...